# remove space on sides of ggplot, even when margin is 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, data-visualization, ggthemes

I'm having a ggplot spacing problem.. probably just not knowing the exact theme element I'm looking for. when I make a ggplot and remove all axis markings, then make all margins 0, there is still a little bit of space between the panel and the outside of the plot that is making my plot asymmetrical. How do I remove this?

```
data.frame(x=1,y=1) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  ggthemes::theme_few() +
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)+
  
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="powderblue",color="black",size=2),
        plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,0,"pt"))
```

see the tiny bit of white space on the left and the bottom. Also, if we move the (nonexistent, I thought) x-scale to the top by adding  `+ scale_x_continuous(position="top")`, the space moves there. So there must be some remnants of scale markings that are creating this space by default. Is there a way to remove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks easier if you add `theme_void() + theme(panel.background = ...)` than setting all those elements to blank. I also don't see the white gap then.

Comment: good point, but I more just wanted to understand what was happening. but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

figured it out- even if you set axis.ticks to element_blank(), you still need to add `axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt")`, to remove the space that they would occupy, then that gets rid of the extra space around the plot.

Answer (score 0):

I output your base example to file and don't believe that there is any additional border. I think what you might be seeing is a part of the RStudio GUI.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(magrittr)

png()
data.frame(x=1,y=1) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  ggthemes::theme_few() +
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)+
  
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="powderblue",color="black",size=2),
        plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,0,"pt"))

dev.off()
```